# What's the gameplay mode in Minecraft that PewDiePie plays?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm so excited watching PewDiePie while playing Minecraft. Especially, the "part 1, part 2, etc." series on him [YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYH8WvNV1YEn9PkI2stxJWMs8GRit66Rz).

It seem he's playing on a PC, but I play Minecraft on an Android device (**Minecraft: Pocket Edition**).

In **Minecraft: PE**, there's two gameplay modes, Creative and Survival mode. Both have many options, which make me confused.

I just want to play Minecraft: PE with a mode similar to the one that PewDiePie plays.

Can you help me find out which gameplay mode and settings to use?

Answer (score 2):

PewDiePie plays survival mode. you can determine this by looking at his status bar, it shows health, hunger, and armor. Creative mode do not have these as the player is invulnerable.